# Too many redirects error after installing ssl certificate

Tags: php, ssl, dns, apache2, cakephp-1.3

After installing ssl certificate my site is not working anymore. I am running my cakephp 1.3 site on vps it work just fine without https but when i enable https it through too many redirects error and when i looked into debug tool i see redirect loop from http (301) -> https (302) -> http -> https

I have added mode_rewrite rules in .htaccess files in all locations

root -> .htaccess, app./.htaccess, app/webroot.htaccess 
I also made few tweaks in the code but i found that it never reach to code when i enable https. right now i am not using .htacess instead i am directly pointing my vhost to webroot folder but still getting loop of redirects

I also checked my dns advanced setting found no issue there.

Redirects image link:
https://gitlab.com/CPW2DO/newsite/uploads/a85856bcea45f463aa906916cf0025be/too_many_redirects_http.png

Dns settings Link:

https://gitlab.com/CPW2DO/newsite/uploads/280ba2d0cbc8b2584726a26a94e76a4b/dns_settings.jpg

Any help would be very much appreciated thanks in advance.

Here how my vhost config.

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/opa/staging/current/app/webroot"

  <Directory /var/www/html/opa/staging/current/app/webroot>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#        AllowOverride All
#        Require all granted
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   </Directory>

  ServerName opa-staging.capwell.nl
  ServerAlias www.opa-staging.capwell.nl
  Redirect permanent / https://opa-staging.capwell.nl/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/opa-staging-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/opa-staging-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<virtualhost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/opa/staging/current/app/webroot"

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cabundle.crt
</virtualhost>
```

Comment: Your HTTPS config needs all the stuff from the HTTP config as well: Directory, ServerName, etc. It doesn't get any of that by default.

Comment: Man, you are a life savior thanks a lot I was struggling with that issue for 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following @Greg Schmidt comment i added my http config to https block and it worked (Yay)

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/opa/staging/current/app/webroot"

  <Directory /var/www/html/opa/staging/current/app/webroot>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   </Directory>

  ServerName opa-staging.capwell.nl
  ServerAlias www.opa-staging.capwell.nl
  Redirect permanent / https://opa-staging.capwell.nl/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/opa-staging-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/opa-staging-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<virtualhost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/opa/staging/current/app/webroot"

  <Directory /var/www/html/opa/staging/current/app/webroot>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   </Directory>

  ServerName opa-staging.capwell.nl
  ServerAlias www.opa-staging.capwell.n

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cabundle.crt
</virtualhost>
```